# Storing an array of references to variables

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I've a set of html select tags I've used PHP to render. :

```
$templates = array( 'Template1', 'Template2', 'Template3', 'Template4');
$templates_dropdown =  '<select required id="templates" name="admin[template_select]">
    <option value="">'.__( 'Pick a template', 'textdomain' ).'</option>';
foreach( $templates as $value){
    $template_value = esc_html( $value );
    $templates_dropdown .= '<option value="' . $template_value . '">' . $template_value . '</option>' . "\n";
}
$templates_dropdown .= '</select>';
```

There are about 5 select tags which I've to close every time like the last line above. Instead of closing each one, is there a way to alter the original variable using variable reference like:

```
$foo = 'Bob';              // Assign the value 'Bob' to $foo
$bar = &$foo;              // Reference $foo via $bar.
$bar = "My name is $bar";  // Alter $bar...
echo $bar;
echo $foo;                 // $foo is altered too.
```

Something along the lines of:

```
 //this doesnt work
    $test = 'world one';
    $test2 = 'world two';
    $test3 = 'world three';
    $close_select_tags = array( &$test, &$test2, &$test3);
    foreach($close_select_tags as $value){
      $value .= 'check';
    }
    echo $test;
    echo "\n";
    echo $test2;
    echo "\n";
    echo $test3;
    echo "\n";
```

I know I can simply use array destructuring or store the select tag variables inside an array, just wondering why storing the references in an array and altering the values doesn't work.

Comment: `foreach($close_select_tags as &$value)`

Comment: ^^^ this. Demo: https://3v4l.org/td17W . You gotta pass it by reference out of the array, as well as into it!